# Poisson noise removal, Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have to add salt&pepper and poisson noises and then remove them. My code:

```
    clear all; close all; clc;


     a = double( imread('spine.tif') )/255;
      a1 = imnoise( a, 'salt & pepper', 0.015 );
     a2 = imnoise( a1, 'poisson' );

      b = medfilt2( a2 );


      grade= sum( sum( abs( a - b ) ) );
         disp( grade);

 subplot( 221 ); imshow( a );
 subplot( 222 ); imshow( a1 );
 subplot( 223 ); imshow( a2 );
 subplot( 224 ); imshow( b );
```

I'm using medfilt2 because I know it is suggested for salt&pepper, but I don't know how to remove poisson and improve my grade function? I was trying different filters, but more I try, the worse grade gets.

Answer (score -1):

Look at this example: http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/remove-noise-from-images.html

```
I = imread('eight.tif');
imshow(I)
J = imnoise(I,'salt & pepper',0.02);
figure, imshow(J)
K = filter2(fspecial('average',3),J)/255;
figure, imshow(K)
L = medfilt2(J,[3 3]);
figure, imshow(L)
```

Use an averaging filter followed by median filter. You do not seem to be using the averaging filter..

Comment: Hmm thanks for your answer, but adding averaging filter made grade function worse